# Return value based on df row and col

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I'm trying to create a df that has col #, row number and cell value based on the lowest value according to a linear model with constraints. column is the col with the lowest value according to the lm output. row is the corresponding row with lowest value, now I want the actual value and i'm having a hard time. if your curious the time value is gmapsdistance output in seconds.

What i'm getting

`> h
  column row time.1 time.2 time.3 time.4 time.5
1     1   1   8262   8262   8262  66357  66357
2     1   2  21386  21386  21386  73307  73307
3     1   3  30698  30698  30698  52547  52547
4     2   4  32711  32711  32711  53006  53006
5     2   5  66156  66156  66156  65205  65205`

What I want is one "time" column with the minimum time corresponding to column and row within aa.

`> h
  column row  time 
1     1   1   8262
2     1   2  21386
3     1   3  30698
4     2   4  53006
5     2   5  65205`

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(lpSolve)


aa <- matrix(c(8262, 21386, 30698, 32711, 66156, 66357, 73307, 52547, 53006, 65205), 
             nrow=5, 
             ncol=2)
aa
#Run aa through a Linear model with lower constraint of 2 and upper constraint of 8
gwide <- aa
k <- ncol(gwide)
n <- nrow(gwide)
dir <- "min"
objective.in <- c(gwide)
A <- t(rep(1, k)) %x% diag(n)
B <- diag(k) %x% t(rep(1, n))
const.mat <- rbind(A, B, B)
const.dir <- c(rep("==", n), rep(">=", k), rep("<=", k))
const.rhs <- c(rep(1, n), rep(2, k), rep(8, k))
res <- lp(dir, objective.in, const.mat, const.dir, const.rhs, all.bin = TRUE)
res

#create a matrix from LM 
soln <- matrix(res$solution, n, k)
soln


column <- apply(soln, 1, which.max)
h <- as.data.frame(column)
h$row = 1:nrow(h)
h$time <- aa[h$row,c(h$column)] #this seems to be where the problem is

h
```

I thought `h$time <- aa[h$row,c(h$column)]` would return a new column named "time" with the value from aa based on the row and column from h but that didn't work out so well. I've been racking my brain for hours and have come up with nothing. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop through the rows of `h` and then extract the values in `aa` using the row and column indices from `h`.

```
h$time <- apply( h, 1, function(x) aa[x[2], x[1]] )
h
#   column row  time
# 1      1   1  8262
# 2      1   2 21386
# 3      1   3 30698
# 4      2   4 53006
# 5      2   5 65205
```

Data:

```
aa <- structure(c(8262, 21386, 30698, 32711, 66156, 66357, 73307, 52547, 
53006, 65205), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))

h <- structure(list(column = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), row = 1:5), .Names = c("column", 
"row"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: this works great! would you mind explaining the function. it does not make sense to me.  `function(x) aa[x[2], x[1]]`  Thank you!

Comment: it is an anonymous function with argument `x` which is passed with the row values of `h`.

Comment: try to use `browser()` inside the function and see the values of `x`

Comment: `apply( h, 1, function(x) { browser(); aa[x[2], x[1]] })` and then you will enter in to debug mode. There you enter `x` to see its values. To go to the next iteration, you can type `n` and then enter